# Firebase Custom domain for email templates Not verify for 7 Days

Tags: firebase, amazon-route53, email-verification

I have configure Custom domain for email templates from Firebase to Route 53 (AWS) I have follow all of instruction from Firebase but stuck in verification progress for 7 days.

[image: Firebase setup]
[image: dig result]

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by removing cloudfront config from the domain on Route 53 AWS.

I think cloudfront is blocking verification access from firebase to destination subdomain. so quick fix for this is remove cloudfront from domain.